# How to disable specific response header when calling Azure Blog Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

when I called the azure blob storage with REST API, I found inside the response header, it discloses the Server and its version.

Are there any ways to disable the **Server key**? I don't want the response header showing the Server information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible to suppress response headers or programmatically control whic response headers to send back.

Comment: Hi, is there a reference article that you can share where this is specified?